# Disable local storage but not cookies in Edge

Tags: local-storage, microsoft-edge

I need to reproduce a problem with a client who uses a particularly "hardened" environment. I suspect they might have local storage somehow disabled but not cookies and I need to reproduce that in my test environment. They are using Microsoft Edge.

Is there any way to block local storage but cookies in Edge - preferably per-site?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to disable it globally, by using a command line flag. Make sure to kill any existing msedge.exe processes using Task Manager for the flag to take effect.

```
taskkill /f /im msedge.exe
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --disable-local-storage
```

Comment: I'm afraid the best you can do is disable local storage globally. If you want to do it on specific sites, you'll have to disable cookies at the same time. Nowadays, modern browsers simply disable all browsing data when you disable cookies, so you cannot disable local storage separately except for this command line flag.